# unity udpclient cannot close on mac

Tags: macos, sockets, unity-game-engine, udpclient

I'm writing a new game with unity3D. I use an unblock UdpClient with triggle to receive player's control command in my new game. I use `udpclient.close()` to close the socket. After I export it as a mac app and play it, I found that the socket I used cannot be close. When I start playing in unity, console show that address is already in use. Finally, I use

```
UdpClient.Client.Close ();
UdpClient.Close ();
((IDisposable)UdpClient).Dispose();
```

to close it. But I fail. I cannot close it at all! `sudo lost -i :(port)` show nothing. But `netstat -anp udp | grep (port)` show a udp4 is on the socket. So strange! Right? How can I close it? 
BTW How can I make the socket be close when player click the close button of the window? Can I override the `Application.Quit()`?
Please help me! Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: `IDisposable` objects are eaiser used with `using(var foo...`

Comment: Thank you! I have tried it after your nice advice. Thank you very much! But the socket is also not close at all. Any way, Thank you!